# Ordenar Tuplas según una secuencia

Tags: python, lista, funciones, ordenamiento, tuplas

Tengo una lista con tuplas:

```
[(0, 1),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 17),
 (3, 2),
 (4, 3),
 (5, 15),
 (6, 5),
 (7, 6),
 (8, 19),
 (9, 8),
 (10, 14),
 (11, 10),
 (12, 13),
 (13, 11),
 (14, 9),
 (15, 12),
 (16, 18),
 (17, 16),
 (18, 7),
 (19, 20),
 (20, 21),
 (21, 23),
 (22, 24),
 (23, 22),
 (24, 0)]
```

Qué función podría hacer para que se ordene según la coincidencia del segundo elemento de la tupla y se haga una secuencia.
Ejemplo:

```
[(0, 1),(1, 4),(4, 3),(3, 2),(2, 17),...
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

¿Tal vez así? Un diccionario puede mapear cada valor a su sucesor. Solo funciona en caso que cada número de la derecha de las tuplas aparece exactamente una vez, y que hay un único bucle que corre por todos los números.

```py
lista = [(0, 1), (1, 4), (2, 17), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 15), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 19), (9, 8),
         (10, 14), (11, 10), (12, 13), (13, 11), (14, 9), (15, 12), (16, 18), (17, 16),
         (18, 7), (19, 20), (20, 21), (21, 23), (22, 24), (23, 22), (24, 0)]
dic = {i: j for i, j in lista}
lista_ordenada = []
i = 0
while True:
    lista_ordenada.append((i, dic[i]))
    i = dic[i]
    if i == 0:
        break
print(lista_ordenada)
```

Resultado:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2), (2, 17), (17, 16), (16, 18), (18, 7), (7, 6), (6, 5),
 (5, 15), (15, 12), (12, 13), (13, 11), (11, 10), (10, 14), (14, 9), (9, 8), (8, 19),
 (19, 20), (20, 21), (21, 23), (23, 22), (22, 24), (24, 0)]
```